# Python process to complete before downstream commands run

Tags: python

I have 2 process running and I want them to complete before further down command executes (at the end of script it prints out that the program has ended). How can I make sure the process completes before printing out that it has ended?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import datetime

class foo:
    def fun1():
        do sthn

    def fun2():
        do sthn

ob = foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Process(target = ob.fun1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = ob.fun2)
    p2.start()

endTime=datetime.datetime.now()
print 'Program Ending time is: ', endTime
```

Comment: The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module waits for processes to complete.

Comment: Are you using the `multiprocessing` module? It's not clear from your code. If you are, you can call the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) method for each `Process` to wait until they complete.

Comment: updated the code, yes I am using multiprocessing module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) method, which blocks until the process is complete.

```
p1.join()
p2.join()
```